# Is Rhino the only interpreter with support for sandboxing and serializable continuations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rhino, continuations, sandbox

I need (a) sandboxing, and (b) serializeable continuations. [I'm exposing server-side game scripting to users](http://weaverengine.com/), and it is extremely async, thus the callback pattern makes code un-readable and very un-approachable for newbie programmers. A continuation-passing style is an alternative, but has the same drawbacks. Async in the sense that a query to the user may take months to complete.

See http://weaverengine.com/platforms for my full list

Serializeable continuations seem like a very elegant solution, but few interpreters support them.

So far, it seems that my only option is Rhino. I was hoping that **NodeJS** or PyPy would work, but the evidence so far points to the contrary.

[Lua seems to support coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106385/which-programming-languages-support-hot-code-swapping-and-or-sandboxing), but I can't find any information on whether it supports serializeable continuations. Lua does sandboxing well.

[NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) has [Jefe](https://github.com/fictorial/jefe) to offer really nice sandboxing, but [nothing so far regarding continuation serialization](https://groups.google.com/group/nodejs-dev/browse_thread/thread/aadbb0354e7cad31).

PyPy also hasn't yet refined their sandboxing and serializeable continuation support to the point where they can be used together, from what I understood on the pypy-dev mailing list.

JavaFlow hints that if all classes implement Serializeable, then java continuations could be serialized. But unless I can run an interpreter for a nice dynamic language on top of JavaFlow, I'm not interested.

Is Java and Rhino my only option?

Is there a branch of NodeJS with continuation support? Any reasonably nice, dynamic language that meets these criteria?

Comment: Just a note: Rhino's Continuations are only available when it is run in interpretive mode (-opt -1). Rhino can be run a couple of ways, and normally it JIT-compiles Java bytecode, or can be compiled ahead-of-time to bytecode using jsc. Of course, running in interpretive mode is slower, so if performance is an issue, this is something important to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

I'm suprised you did not mention Scheme, as that is the language where continuations where pioneered. [SISC](http://sisc-scheme.org/) for example is a Scheme interpreter running on the JVM that supports serializable continuations. These are used for example in the [SISCweb](http://siscweb.sourceforge.net/overview.html) framework.

For sandboxing you could use the builtin security features of the jvm.

Comment: Thanks! I've read about continuations on other versions of scheme, but those implementations were *not* serializeable. I'm not sure if Scheme is the best language to teach people how to program with - I consider it advanced, but extremely powerful and useful.

Comment: Racket has excellent sandboxing support[1]. It also supoprts serializable continuations in its slightly restricted "web-server" language[2]. And if you don't like the web-server language, you could use it as an example to implement your own sandboxed scripting language with serializable continuations.

1. https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html
2. https://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/stateless.html#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Flang%2Fabort-resume..rkt%29._call-with-serializable-current-continuation%29%29

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to serialize continuations in [Gambit-C](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of that version of Scheme before. I'm not sure Scheme is suitable as an introductory language, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Lua 5.1.4 and [Pluto](https://github.com/hoelzro/pluto). Seems to be a good choice so far.